# Show IconBadgeNumber after push notification while app background or closed (Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, notifications

In my Xamarin.iOS project I use Azure Notification Hub to send push notification to my application.

I can control my IconBadgeNumber with this code in `AppDelegate` class.

```
 var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Badge, null);
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

I can count number of my push notification when they come:

```
 public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
 {
     ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
     UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; ;
 }
```

But it will work only if my application is opened. How I can count push notifications for IconBadgeNumber when my app is backgrouned or close?

Answer (score 0):

The count of  push notifications is up to your settings in the push service.Such as

```
Message message = Message.builder()
.setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
.putHeader("apns-priority", "10")
.setAps(Aps.builder()
.setAlert(ApsAlert.builder()
.setTitle("$GOOG up 1.43% on the day")
.setBody("$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.")
.build())
.setBadge(42)
.build())
.build())
.setTopic("industry-tech")
.build();
```

You can set the number of badge `setBadge(xxx)`.